# Maintaining state of Bootstrap accordion with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, state, accordion

I'm using ajax to recieve data from an API, which executes every second. To display the data in a web interface, the HTML code with a bootstrap accordion containing the data gets rewritten for every update. I want to use an  accordion so the user can decide where and when he wants to see detailed information. Cause of rewriting the HTML code for the accordion every second the state also gets overwritten every time and it will collapse/show independent of the current state. Is there a good way to save the current state and only update the data inside of the accordions?

I tried gaping the state inside the class before deleting the HTML code from the last pass through and insert the class with the state 'show' or '' to maintain the state ('statusShow[d]') but it doesn't find the Element with the ID ('collapse' + d). When the same code is in .always this problem does not occur but  (I guess .always is executed instantly after .done) it does not work.

```js
let statusShow = ['show', 'show', 'show', 'show']

function getInput() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "./Input",
        type : 'POST'
    })


        .done((data) => {


            let dataJson = JSON.parse(data.replace(/\\'/g, "'"))

                      
            // The code I tried graping the state of last pass through
            for (let d = 0; d < data_length; d++) {
                let classShow = document.getElementById('collapse' + d).className

                if (classShow.includes('show')){
                    statusShow[d] = 'show'
                }
                else {
                    statusShow[d] = ''
                }



            $("#accordionChar").html('')

            for (let d = 0; d < data_length; d++) {

                $("#accordionChar").append(`

                    <div class="accordion-item `+ changeBgColor(dataJson) +` border                                                                    border-dark">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header border border-dark" id="heading` + d + `">
                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed `+ changeBgColor(dataJson) +` fw-bolder text-dark" type="button"
                                data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse` + d + `"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse` + d + `">
                                Characteristic `
                                + d + 
                            `</button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="collapse` + d + `" class="accordion-collapse collapse `**+ statusShow[d] +**`"
                            aria-labelledby="heading` + d + `">
                            <div class="accordion-body">
                            <div class="row" id="table_info` + d + `">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="table_content` + d + `">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`)

                // Appends data to the accordion body
                makeTable(data, d)
                
            }
        })

        .fail((data) => {

        })

        .always((data) => {

            setTimeout(function() {
                getInput();
            }, 1000);
    });
};
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionChar">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by updating the status with an onclick on every accordion button.

```
function updateShow(d) {

    if (statusShow[d] === '') {
        statusShow[d] = 'show'
        collapsed[d] = ''
    }
    else {
        statusShow[d] = ''
        collapsed[d] = 'collapsed'
    }
    
}
```